# html simple align, in table and page

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this simple HTML table.

```
<table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:1000px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">BB<br />
            BB<br />
            BB</th>
            <th scope="col">AA</th>
            <th scope="col">AA</th>
            <th scope="col">AA</th>
            <th scope="col">AA</th>
            <th scope="col">AA</th>
            <th scope="col">AA</th>
            <th scope="col">AA</th>
            <th scope="col">AA</th>
            <th scope="col">AA</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

But I want AA cells to be aling in top verticaly, (now its aling center verticaly),
and also I want the space above the table and left the table to be 0.

Render the simple code in html I will understand what I mean.

Now I want to link a simple CSS to make this features, but how can I make this?

Update, the solution in CSS was:

```
th{
vertical-align:top;
}
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target only the cells containing `aa` using the following CSS:

```
th[scope="col"] {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BLcEV/)

Comment: thx, but how can i remove the space from above and left the table?

Comment: Set the padding on the body to 0: `body { padding: 0 }`.

Answer (score 2):

**try this**

```
th{
vertical-align:top;
}
```

**or only for AA**

```
th[scope="col"]{
vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: thx, but how can i remove the space from above and left the table?

Comment: Can u sho me screen shoot

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:1000px">
    <thead>
        <tr style="vertical-align: top;">
            <th scope="row">BB<br />
            BB<br />
            BB</th>
            <th scope="col">AA</th>
            <th scope="col">AA</th>
            <th scope="col">AA</th>
            <th scope="col">AA</th>
            <th scope="col">AA</th>
            <th scope="col">AA</th>
            <th scope="col">AA</th>
            <th scope="col">AA</th>
            <th scope="col">AA</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
```